# How to rewrite url effectively is asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, iis-7.5

We have URLs like:

```
domain.com/products-in-{CityName}/
```

When the user comes to such URLs, we are rewriting the URL by .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteMap map_cities txt:../../urlmappings/map_cities.txt

RewriteRule 

^products-in-(.*)/                        

productsearch.aspx?city=${map_cities:${lowercase:$1}}&cityname=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

There are two choices we have to accomplish this:

1. Do by hard coding all cities id and name in map_cities. But I feel reading from text file would be slow.
2. Using iis to rewrite. I don't know much about it but i read brief article here- [rewriting urls with iis](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Which would be better to use? Performance and other aspects?

Comment: There is no real disadvantage in using rewrite maps. Its contents will be cached by the web server, so IIS can find matching results fast. I would however ditch the .htaccess because an additional module like Helicon Ape uses a lot of extra RAM. We noticed a ~ 300% memory usage increase per application pool when Helicon Ape is used. So do 2, with the text file / rewrite map mentioned, see http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: ok. So using iis rewriting is better than using htaccess, right? does these htaccess rules require read operation from text file for every request, or it has some caching. where can i learn more about how url rewriting works with .htaccess file?

Comment: In my opinion it's best to use IIS URL Rewriting, because you need an additional IIS module to support .htaccess files. Helicon Ape[1] is one of those. Helicon Ape's mod_rewrite implementation does support RewriteMaps's [2], and those are cached as well. So yes, the rewritemap file needs to be read, but not for every request.

[1] http://www.helicontech.com/ape/
[2] http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_rewrite.htm#RewriteMap

Comment: Is there any performance impact in using .htaccess- because i wonder if rewrite map does read from text file for every request. (RewriteMap map_cities txt:../../urlmappings/map_cities.txt). Complete thing mentioned in question above. We are concerned only about performance.

Comment: Have you read my first comment? There _is_ a performance impact, because you need to install an additional module in IIS. And we noticed a ~ 200-300% memory usage increase using Helicon Ape